# Rails bundler: "Could not find tilt-1.3.5 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems, bundler

I have never encountered this problem before so I really don't know where to start looking for answers... despite Google ofcourse which seems to be an empty road concerning this topic.

When I try to push my application to heroku I get this message:

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find tilt-1.3.5 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

I have destroyed my gemset and started over numerous amounts of times, as well as flat-out required tilt in my Gemfile, but no luck, I still get this message.

Like I said, I have never got this error until yesterday and assumed it was a minor bug that would be fixed.  Seems as if that isn't the case, and I am scratching my head trying to figure out what needs to be done to fix this issue.

Any suggestions?

EDIT GEMFILE

```
source 'https://rubygems.org/'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'thin'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails_autolink'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.14.1'
end
```

Comment: can you show us your gem file

Comment: Yes I had modified to show the Gemfile.  Note I tried removing my Gemfile.lock and committing the changes but still not luck.

Comment: Try downgrading it. Just saw something about it in Heroku site.

Comment: downgrading you mean how? Rails version?

Comment: you can choose a specific version it by doing this     gem "tilt", "1.3.4" . mine is running 1.3.4 and it works with heroku. just put that in and bundle and try again

Comment: Having the same issue with capistrano deploy. Locally can install tilt-1.3.5, installing manually on the server works too. Bundler via capistrano fails. Locking to 1.3.4 works fine for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same error.  As iRichLau [noted in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280081/rails-bundler-could-not-find-tilt-1-3-5-in-any-of-the-sources/15291273#comment21561029_15280081), locking to 1.3.4 or 1.3.6 works.

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'tilt', '1.3.4' # or '1.3.6' is now out and also works.
```

Then bundle:

```
bundle update tilt
```

Make sure the commit message is commensurate with the ridiculousness of this phantasmal error. ;)

Answer (score 1):

running `bundle update` and then `git add` before pushing should fix it

Comment: `bundle update tilt` was all I needed.  Not entirely sure why it couldn't find it earlier.

Comment: Could you explain what rvm gemset pristine actually does?  It says "restores to pristine condition".  I am confused how this works.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had 2 different version of the brightbox gem.

The newer brightbox gem requires a newer version of bundle.

So in the top of my deploy.rb I forced the brightbox gem version to be:

```
gem 'brightbox', '2.3.8'
```